# How to run script generated by publish for SQL Data project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sqlcmd, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using SSDT (in SQL Data Project) in Visual Studio 2013. When I publish the database, I can

- Do a direct publish (click the publish button)
- Generate the script, then execute in Visual Studio

But the script does pretty much nothing (apparently) if I copy it to SSMS and try to execute it (in SQLCMD mode).

How would I execute a generated script outside of Visual Studio?  Do I have to use sqlcmd.exe? And if so, are there certain command line parameters that I would need to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you generating the script against the same database for which you want to run the script? When you look at the results, are there any actual changes? Normally you'd either publish directly or use sqlcmd to run the script against the correct server/db, but if nothing is happening, I'd look more closely at the script. There could be an option enabled to only run the script if the server and DB names are "correct", but I think you have to choose to enable that option.

Comment: Actually, the problem may have been that I there are audit tables with an appended A_ in the database. I think I updated the design of that table and didn't update the design of the actual table. Doh! I've had no issues since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Peter helped me look at the issue from a new angle. It wasn't a database problem, but a table issue. The database has an auditing table for every table. I was updating the Address table (I thought), but instead updated the A_Address table. It was all working fine. The first run updated the audit table, subsequent runs didn't (of course), but I was checking the Address table for the update.  Doh!  New database, new technology....